# Update datalabel position after Heatmap resize with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am struggling with the position of the datalabels on an heatmap after resizing the window.

I have made an function which is getting called when the window resizes, because it is important to keep the map square:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    width = $("#container").width();
    height = width;
    chart.setSize(width, height, doAnimation = true);
});
```

The chart resizes fine, however the datalabels aren't changing their position.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Warforce/dt4RM/11/) to show the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using some old version of heatmaps. Try to use the latest one, see: http://jsfiddle.net/9ExnF/

```
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this was part of the problem. It seems I needed to use `{ x: 0, y: 1, value: 234, color: green}` instead of `{ row: 0, col: 1, y: 234, color: green}`